# How to print text above the input line while typing (python)

Tags: python

I'm writing a server-client chat with python and I have this problem when using the client: if I recive a message while typing text gets messed up beetween the output lines. I'm using two separate threads, one for sending input text and one for printing messages from the server.

What i get (input: helloworld):

```
[message]    
[message]
<I start to type>
he[message]
llo[message]
worl[message]
d| <I press enter to send message>

-> helloworld
```

What i would like to get:

```
[message]    
[message]
<I start to type>
[message]
[message]
[message]
helloworld| <I press enter to send message>

-> helloworld
```

or

```
[message]    
[message]
<I start to type>
helloworld|
[message]
[message]
[message]
<I press enter to send message>

`-> helloworld
```

`

So new messages get printed above (better) or under the typing line.
I tried to refresh messages only after pressing enter to send the message, but i want the chat to be real-time.

Full code (if you are interested): https://github.com/MattSini912/mschat/blob/main/MSCHAT/src/client.py
(input line: 216)

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: There is no easy way to do it and it requires taking control over underlying tty buffer (which is very system and terminal dependent). Ipython does that so it's definitely possible. Take a look at the *curses* library, I think it might provide what you need.

Comment: I believe it might be easier to make it into a GUI application than messing with tty.